# find a list of interval values from a vector in r

Tags: r, function, vector, intervals

Say I have a numeric vector as in `X = 1:10000`. Is there currently a way in `R` to obtain a list of 10 intervals from `X` as shown in my `Desired_output`?

```
Desired_output = list(c(0,1000), c(1001,2000),  c(2001,3000),  c(3001,4000),  c(4001,5000),  
                      c(5001,6000), c(6001,7000), c(7001,8000), c(8001,9000), c(9001,10000))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `seq`

```
Map(`c`, c(0, seq(1001, 10000, by = 1000)), seq(1000, 10000, by = 1000))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1]    0 1000

[[2]]
[1] 1001 2000

[[3]]
[1] 2001 3000

[[4]]
[1] 3001 4000

[[5]]
[1] 4001 5000

[[6]]
[1] 5001 6000

[[7]]
[1] 6001 7000

[[8]]
[1] 7001 8000

[[9]]
[1] 8001 9000

[[10]]
[1]  9001 10000
```

Comment: Just curious, how about if my desired list was: `list(c(0,1000),c(1001,  2000),  
                   c(2001,  3000),  c(3001,  4000),  
                   c(4001,  5000),  c(5001,6000),
                   c(6001,7000), c(7001, 8000), 
                   c(8001, 9000), c(9001, 10000),
                   c(10001, 1e7))`

Comment: @SimonHarmel You can just append the output of this with `c(out, list(c(10001, 1e7)))`